# How i want to set other user as admin for specific app in Apple Developer program

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, itunes, apple-developer

Im trying to set other person as admin for specific apps (To give access create provisioning profile). However, when i set the user as admin, it will open to access to all my apps in Apple Developer Program. Please help me out.

Comment: As far as I know, the admin role gets access to all apps in the developer account. Have you tried the App Manager role instead?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not possible to restrict the access of the role `admin`. It's only possible to roles "smaller" than `admin`, i.e. `appmanager`, `developer`, `marketing` etc.

There's also no way to give a person specific app-level access on https://developer.apple.com/account (Apple Developer Portal). The app access is only for https://appstoreconnect.apple.com (App Store Connect)

You might want to check out the official documentation over at https://developer.apple.com/support/roles/

Please note that if you have a personal/individual account, it's not possible to add people to Apple Developer Portal. It's only something company accounts can do.

Answer (score -1):

Go to http://appstoreconnect.apple.com/ on your main account.

Move to `Users and Access` Select `Developer` select `Plus` button.

Enter valid address.
Press on `All apps` and select that app what you want [image]

**Note** from `Appstoreconnect` regarding `admin` user role for some application:
`Only active users with App Manager, Developer, Marketer or Sales roles can be edited.`

Comment: I tried this but when i set as admin, still that person can access to all my apps. Just want to allow specific apps only.

Comment: @fnsmp Change his role to Developer and select only one app

Comment: Admin always has access to all apps. You cannot restrict app-level access for admins. Also app-level access is only for App Store Connect, but never for Apple Developer center.

Comment: @Max yes you are right, it should be changed to App Manager, Developer, Marketer or Sales